# $W$ is $\sigma$-invariant i.e., $\sigma(W) \subset W$ implies that $W$ has a basis consisting of elements of $\mathbb F_{q}^n.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Consider the field extension $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ over $\mathbb F_q$ and a $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ linear subspace $W \subset \mathbb F_{q^m}^n.$ Let $\sigma:\mathbb F_{q^m} \to \mathbb F_{q^m}$ be the Frobenious map given by $x \mapsto x^q.$ Also consider the action of $\sigma$ on $\mathbb F_{q^m}^n$ as $\sigma(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(a_{1}^q,\ldots,a_{n}^q).$ Then I have to show the following thing:

> $W$ is $\sigma$-invariant i.e., $\sigma(W) \subset W$ implies that $W$ has a basis consisting of elements of $\mathbb F_{q}^n.$

For any $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb F_{q^m}^n,$  $Tr(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb F_{q}^n$. But we can't show that any basis of $W$ can be lift via the Trace map to a basis of $W$ in $\mathbb F_q^n,$ since Trace is surjective only, it is not injective. I need some idea to prove this. Many thanks.

Comment: If $p \nmid m$ then take any non-zero $w\in W$, take $c\in F_{q^m}$ such that $(cw)_j\in F_q^*$ we have $Tr(cw)\ne 0$, put it in the basis and repeat with the quotient space $W / F_{q^m} Tr(cw)$. Otherwise we can assume $p=m$, take a $F_q$-basis of $W$, $\sigma$ acts on it as a matrix $M\in GL_d(F_q)$, then $M^p = I$ thus $(M-I)^p = 0$, take a vector in $\ker(M-I)$, it gives some $v=\sigma(v)\in W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following trick works.

Assume that $\dim_{\Bbb{F}_{q^m}}W=k\le n$. Let $\mathcal{B}=\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k\}$ be a basis of $W$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$. Consider the $k\times n$ matrix $M$ with rows $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k$. Because elementary row operations on $M$ simply replace the basis $\mathcal{B}$ with another one, we can, without loss of generality, assume that $M$ is in a reduced row echelon form.

> I claim that the rows of $M$ have entries in $\Bbb{F}_q$.

The proof is easy. Assume that the initial $1$ on row number $i$ of $M$ (aka the pivot) is on column $j_i$. So the $i$th row $w_i$ of $M$ has a $1$ at position $j_i$, and a zero at all the other pivot positions $j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_{i-1}<j_{i+1}<\ldots<j_k$. The key is that $w_i$ is *the only vector in $W$ with these specific coordinates at the pivot positions.* This is because those component give the coordinates of any vector of $W$ w.r.t. the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Guess what, $\sigma(w_i)$ is also such a vector!
Implying that we must have $\sigma(w_i)=w_i$! But it is well known that $\sigma(w)=w$ is equivalent to all the components of $w$ being in $\Bbb{F}_q$. QED.

---

The argument can be generalized to $G$-invariant subspaces $W$ of $L^n$ for any Galois extension $L/K$, $G=Gal(L/K)$. Such a subspace has a basis of vectors from $K^n$.

Comment: Permuting the columns was not strictly necessary. It was just simpler to formulate the argument when I was able to refer to the $k$ first components.

Comment: But permuting the columns changes the subspace spanned by the rows, which is therefore no longer $W$. So your argument in fact becomes more complicated (if you want to maintain that the conclusion is nonetheless good enough for purpose). Or stated differently, the fact that such permuting is not strictly necessary is essential to the argument.

Comment: Actually I also solved  it exactly in your way(Only after posting this problem). I didn't delete, thought some elegant way it can be solved. But since you also solved this way this is possibly a natural solution. Thank you @Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: If you do not want to permute the columns then also the arguments hold good @MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen Do you have any alternative solution or idea ?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I rewrote the proof without mentioning that column permutation. Do you find the present formulation easier to read? Such column permutations are frequent in coding theory, so may be I misjudged the amount of extra mental effort it causes to a reader.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, the proof looks fine now. Personally in an echelon form I call the initial nonzero entries of each row "pivots" and frequently distinguish columns with and without pivot. With this terminology you can simply say that every row has $1$ as its pivot and has a zero entry in every remaining pivot column, and it is the only vector in $W$ which has those entries in the pivot columns. But your answer is perfectly fine as it is now.

Comment: Thank @Marc. I should have known that terminology but forgot.